# Bootstrap Datetimepicker span breaks

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I use Bootstrap 3 Datepicker v4 but something breaks and I cannot fix it. I think it's the input which break the css.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class='col-sm-6'>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                    <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
            });
        </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

**RESULT**

What should I overwrite, in order to remove the margin between the span and the input?

[image]

Comment: Check this https://jsfiddle.net/Eonasdan/0Ltv25o8/

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't work. When I focus on the second input it doesn't open the calendar, but when I focus in the first it opens the calendar and the value goes in both inputs.

Comment: It's with your code, https://jsfiddle.net/cmedina/0Ltv25o8/3150/

Comment: Yes, you are right. Your first answer is the solution in my problem. I can make it work without the button. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

I tried to recreate the issue using [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/J7eyhdBBNY), but was unable to.

So try changing the width of the `div`, like so:

```
<div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1' style="width: 90%" <!-- Or something like that depending on what your preference is -->>
    <input type='text' class="form-control" />
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
        </span>
</div>
```

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: The width changes but the margin remains. It is just smaller.

Comment: @Mitsos Have you inspected the element to ensure that there isn't any custom css?

Comment: I inspected it, but there is nothing between those two.

Comment: Thanks for your time. Solved